# What is the MD5 sumcheck for elementryos-6.1-stable20211218-rc.iso?

Tags: live-installation

What is the MD5 sumcheck for elementryos-6.1-stable20211218-rc.iso ?

Answer (score 0):

Good question. Strangely, there is none available on their website (or this is on-purpose so the iso is not shared and verified).

File: elementaryos-6.1-stable.20211218-rc.iso

SHA256:
35c8086bc0af8ccc5ef8629225b215b1742b3a90b475f9f47723b18a315d86a7

MD5:
17b373306a9ee304ee3d544ee9cea97a

Answer (score 0):

they provide sha256 checksum for latest iso. can be seen here https://elementary.io/docs/installation#verify-your-download